# Why can't Mathematica confirm this simple identity?

Tags: summation, proof

It is well known that for positive integer $n\geq2$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!^2}{(n^2-1^2)\ldots(n^2-k^2)}=\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{2(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2 \binom{2n}{n}}.
$$
This identity appears in Apéry's proof of the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$.

I tried to verify this claim numerically using Mathematica, by taking the difference of the two sides and hopefully getting $0$ as a result (for various values of $n$). My code is:

```
n = 5;
N[Sum[((-1)^(k - 1) ((k - 1)!)^2)/(Sum[(n^2 - j^2), {j, 1, k}]), {k, 1, n - 1}] - (1/n^2 - (2*(-1)^(n - 1) )/(n^2*Binomial[2 n, n]))]
```

Couldn't be any more straightforward, really.

To my surprise, I *never* get $0$ as a result, for any values of $n$. For $n=5$ in the example above, I get

```
-0.46895
```

and for $n=6$ I get

```
4.32057
```

These are clearly incorrect. I went through my code many times, but found no mistake. What am I doing wrong?

---

*Reference:*

A. Van der Poorten:  "[A Proof that Euler Missed...](http://pracownicy.uksw.edu.pl/mwolf/Poorten_MI_195_0.pdf)"

Comment: I think that you are considering the denominator in the lhs incorrectly. Try replacing it with `Apply[Times, n^2 - Range[k]^2]`.

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what Indeed, that solved it! Do you know why using Sum[ ] instead failed there?

Comment: Because you wanted the product, not the sum.

Comment: Voting to close as "simple mistake". Nevertheless, it might be useful to know how that kind of mistakes can be identified more easily, that is why I posted an answer.

Comment: It is just a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series). Easy to see without MA. Voting to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple mistake using `Sum` instead of `Product`. (That is easier to see by converting the formula/cell into Standard form or Traditional form.)

[image]

Comment: The result of  LHS= `Sum[((-1)^(k - 1) ((k - 1)!)^2)/(Product[(n^2 - j^2), {j, 1, k}]), {k,
   1, n - 1}]` is not right, I don't know what had  happened.

Comment: @cvgmt Mathematica v12 evaluates `Sum[((-1)^(k - 1) ((k - 1)!)^2)/
 Product[n^2 - j^2, {j, 1, k}] , {k, 1, n - 1}]==1/n^2` ???

Comment: Indeed! Such an oversight... Thank you for your reply